# Unable to Handle Exception Thrown in Custom JSON Deserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, jax-rs

Below is my code where I am using Custom Deserializer in a DTO class and an exception is thrown(ex:- when 12 is passed, instead of "12") which I am catching in catch block and throwing my own CustomException. But that CustomException is not going to the front-end. Not sure how to handle this/did I miss anything on this. I tried, CustomExceptionMapper also, but not working. Below is my code. Any Help/Suggestion would be appreciable.

Edited the question and added full code. In console, message is printing as 
"Input is :: null ::" and 'SUCCESS' response is coming instead of 'BAD_REQUEST' response mentioned in 'CustomExceptionMapper'. 'createService' is a method in Controller class.

As per my analysis (my analysis may be wrong also), CustomException is throwing while deserializing the DTO and as there is nothing like try/catch in DTO, application is unable to handle it.

```
    public class StringOnlyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {  

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)  
        {
            try {
                if (!JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(jsonParser.getCurrentToken())) {                    
                    throw deserializationContext.wrongTokenException(jsonParser, String.class, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING,
                            "String expected");
                } else {                    
                    return jsonParser.getValueAsString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {                     
                throw new CustomException(e);
            }
        }
    }
************************************************************************************

    public class RequestDTO {

        @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide reqId")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = StringOnlyDeserializer.class)
        private String reqId;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide name")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = StringOnlyDeserializer.class)
        private String name;

    //getters and setters
    }
***********************************************************************
    @Component
    @Provider
    public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<CustomException> {
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(CustomException exception) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
***********************************************************************
    public Response createService(@Valid RequestDTO requestDTO) {
            logger.info("Input is :: " + requestDTO + " ::");
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("SUCCESS").build();
        }
```

Comment: why are you posting just parts of the code, how is it registered, were is the CustomExceptionMapper, where is the error when you say "but not working" How did it not work? produce a minimal working example.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf added the full required code

Comment: Are you using jackson in a spring boot application? If so you need to register the provider manually. `@Component` will register it as a spreang bean, but spring boot has no idea what a exceptionmapper is. Your problem is that you are mixing java ee and spring boot. Decide what you want to use, spring web or jax-rs (jackson) and then read the spring documentation how to implement one or the other.

Comment: I have added 'ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper' in my code to catch 'ConstraintViolationException' in the same manner as 'CustomExceptionMapper' which is perfectly working. My problem is why the 'CustomException' thrown is not getting caught by 'CustomExceptionMapper' and how to resolve it.

Comment: Post the code that works